# Stop run selection in vscode with python when errors occurred

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, spyder

I just made the transition from spyder to vscode. And even if I find vscode much better, I'm still trying to find some things that I had with spyder and that I don't have anymore with vscode.

One of them is about run selection.

When I run multiple lines in a python terminal, if an error occurs at one moment the other lines will be run also. Most of the times I miss the error because it is displays in my terminal but above the over lines which have bien run.

For example if I run this part of code with run selection

```
print(3/3)
print(3/0)
print(3/1)
```

it will display something like that

```
>>> print(3/3)
1.0
>>> print(3/0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
>>> print(3/1)
3.0
```

Instead of that I would like to display

```
>>> print(3/3)
    print(3/0)
    print(3/1)
1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

I have what I want when I run this but it's not the point

```
print(3/3); print(3/0); print(3/1);
```